# Views not appearing on the android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, preview

I am using android studio in ubuntu 18.04 When I select my .xml file in the layout folder in the res folder I am getting this
[image]

But when I try to drag the views from the left panel like textview or button  I can see them being dragged but they don't appear on the mobile screen. Please help me with this and comment if more information is required.
Thanks

Comment: see if the buttons are in XML or not.

Comment: How do I check that

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the AppTheme above the preview to something else like DarkTheme.NoActionbar or anything.
[image]

Change the theme here.

Comment: Can you please highlight which part by are you talking about. Please highlight on the image I have given so that it will be easier for me to follow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It got solved by changing the 
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` to 
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` 
in the app > res > values > styles.xml